# C# Using Regex.Replace() with Interop.Excel in order to clean up excel file column(s)

Tags: regex, excel, replace, office-interop, worksheet

**Summary:**

Using **Interop.Excel** reference, **and after opening** the .csv file my code cleans up headers, makes adjustments, and applies filters on top row. ***However***, the last step I need and cannot figure out is, using `Regex.Replace("string, but would need to be entire column B"), @"\s+"," ");` in order to replace unnecessary multiple spaces in one line of code ie: `"Hello        world,     how are     you    doing?"` into this `"Hello world, how are you doing?"`. I don't want to use multiple instances of Replace() because it can vary between each row in column B.

**What I have tried:** 
I have tried multiple ways to call in the column B, even trying to put it into an array of some sort, but even that doesn't make much sense to me.

`Regex.Replace(xlWorkSheet.Range["B1"].EntireColumn.ToString(), @"\s+", " ");` clearly this doesn't work. 
3.

Comment: The input to `Regex.Replace` is a `string`, so you will have to loop all the  cells where you need to run clean up. That is, if you want to use a regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you for the idea, I considered that might take quite a bit depending on amount of records; I'll check back later in case I get it to work. I appreciate you.

Comment: would it be easier to just use the Trim formula for the entire column range?  You should be able to apply the function in one pass, then copy the data over the column, and remove the formula.  It'd be quicker than looping through the entire range cell by cell.